# Flutter Quiz Api tried calling []() NoSuchMethodError

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, dart

I cant get data from the API.

I want to fetch the question String from the JSON but it throws an error

ERROR:

```
I/flutter ( 6609): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.

I/flutter ( 6609): Receiver: 0

I/flutter ( 6609): Tried calling: [] ("question")
```

MY API:

```
{
   "response_code":0,
   "results":[
      {
         "category":"Entertainment: Video Games",
         "type":"multiple",
         "difficulty":"medium",
         "question":"What&#039;s the famous line Vaas says in &quot;Far Cry 3&quot;?",
         "correct_answer":"Did I ever tell you the definition of Insanity?",
         "incorrect_answers":[
            "Have I failed to entertain you?",
            "You&#039;re my b*tch!",
            "Maybe your best course...would be to tread lightly."
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":"Entertainment: Video Games",
         "type":"boolean",
         "difficulty":"easy",
         "question":"&quot;Half-Life 2&quot; runs on the Source Engine.",
         "correct_answer":"True",
         "incorrect_answers":[
            "False"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My Method:

```
Future<void> showQuestions() async {
  try {
   
    final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=2'));
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    extractedData.forEach((id, data) {
      print(data["question"]);
    });
 }catch (err) {
  print(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you forget to go into the `results` part of the JSON.

Comment: if i print(data) without ["question"] then i get the results but i want only the question

Comment: Yes, but you are not traversing the correct data structure. You need to traverse the "results" in your JSON. Right now, you are traversing the root of the JSON which contains "response_code" and "results".

Comment: okay i understand but how can i traverse the JSON i normaly do data["question"] on firebase but here its little bit diffrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you iterate through your map and tried to get `question` but your first key `response_code` doesn't have this property. beside if you iterate to your second key `results` it is a of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` where you can't retrieve the questions with the bracket `['question']` since it is a `List`. To fix this you have to get the `results` first and then iterate through it.

```
Future<void> showQuestions() async {
  try {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=2'));
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final List<dynamic> results = extractedData['results'];
    for (final result in results) {
      print(result['question']);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not so sure that type cast is going to work. Since `extractedData` comes from JSON parsing the type returned from `extractedData['results']` would end up being `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: if i change List<Map<String, dynamic>> to List<dynamic> it works! thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Can you mark my answer as accepted for others?